# How do I calculate how far an object has travelled in a specific time?

Tags: python, scripting

I can't find any reference to calculate an object travelled distance along a time range. I think it could be done by using Matrix difference from frame to frame.  I need distance travelled on each frame. I am expecting a cumulative value for each frame.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Object distance between frames and total movement length can be done. Set frame_start and frame_end variables.
It calculates selected object distance.

```
import bpy

o = bpy.context.object
total = 0
frame_start = 0
frame_end = 10
bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frame_start)

for frame in range(frame_start+1,frame_end+1):

    loc1 = o.matrix_world.to_translation()
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frame)
    loc2 = o.matrix_world.to_translation()
    dist = (loc1-loc2).length
    print ("Frames:", frame-1,"-", frame,"distance:", dist)    
    total += dist

print ("Total distance:", total)
```

Comment: Thank you, edited the answer.

Comment: Edited answer: replaced o.location to o.matrix_world.to_translation().

Comment: JuhaW, do you know if it would be possible to calculate the moved distance while in playback mode, and use the result in a driver? This would be useful for a wheel rotation driver.